# magento multiselect product attribute not showing option labels on frontend

Tags: attributes, product, multi-select, magento-1.9

I have checked lot and tried many things, but I am still not getting the product multiselect selected values label on product view page.

I have product attribute called package which is multiselect, 
Code that create the product attribute

```
$this->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'package',
    array(
        'group'             => 'Package',
        'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'default'           => '',
        'label'             => 'Package',
        'input'             => 'multiselect',
        'type'              => 'text',
        'source'            => 'npm_recurrex/package_source',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'is_visible'        => 1,
        'required'          => 0,
        'searchable'        => 0,
        'filterable'        => 0,
        'unique'            => 0,
        'comparable'        => 0,
        'visible_on_front'  => 0,
        'user_defined'      => 1,
    )
);
```

this works fine, I am successfully saving the product.
But in frontend product view page when I say

```
Mage::log(print_r($_product->getData('package'), true));
```

Its prints the result as 1,2
But I wanted to display option labels of multiselect not option id's.
So I tried with this code

```
Mage::log(print_r($_product->getAttributeText('package'), true));
```

It prints nothing, just blank space :(.

I have checked this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34593/get-multiple-select-product-attributes-option-labels-instead-of-option-ids) but no use.

I am confused with this, Where I am wrong? and what is the wrong thing?

Can anybody explain me what is happening in my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show Drop Down or Multiple select value of an attribute product you should do something like this:

```html
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
$customAttributeValue = $attributes['custom_attribute']->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
Mage::log($customAttributeValue);
```